# Spinning up EMR from AWS lambda results in "no identity-based policy allows the elasticmapreduce:RunJobFlow action"

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-iam, amazon-emr

I'm trying to create an AWS lambda function that spins up an EMR cluster using a Java SDK.

My execution role contains the policy `AmazonEMRFullAccessPolicy_v2` (see cloud formation below), but I have the following error:

```
"errorMessage": "User: arn:aws:sts::978841875846:assumed-role/bex-one-identity-recon_role_us-west-2/bex-one-identity-recon 
is not authorized to perform: elasticmapreduce:RunJobFlow
 on resource: arn:aws:elasticmapreduce:us-east-1:978841875846:cluster/* because 
no identity-based policy allows the elasticmapreduce:RunJobFlow action 
(Service: AmazonElasticMapReduce; Status Code: 400; Error Code: AccessDeniedException; Request ID: 189c923c-c3d5-44ec-a04b-8448dd4105f3)",
```

Cloudformation:

```yaml
  LambdaRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      RoleName: !Sub "${KumoRole}_role_${AWS::Region}"
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service: lambda.amazonaws.com
            Action: sts:AssumeRole
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: !Sub "${KumoRole}-cloudwatch_policy_${AWS::Region}"
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: 2012-10-17
            Statement:
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - logs:PutLogEvents
                  - logs:CreateLogGroup
                  - logs:CreateLogStream
                Resource:
                  - arn:aws:logs:*:*:*
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEMRFullAccessPolicy_v2
```

Lambda code

```java
    public String handleRequest(Void event, Context context) {
        AmazonElasticMapReduce emr = AmazonElasticMapReduceClientBuilder.standard()
                .withRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1)
                .build();

        HadoopJarStepConfig hadoopJarStepConfig = new HadoopJarStepConfig()
                .withJar("command-runner.jar")
                .withArgs(...);


        StepConfig stepConfig = new StepConfig()
                .withName("Recon job")
                .withActionOnFailure("TERMINATE_JOB_FLOW")
                .withHadoopJarStep(hadoopJarStepConfig);

        Application spark = new Application().withName("Spark");

        RunJobFlowRequest request = new RunJobFlowRequest()
                .withName("Spark Cluster")
                .withReleaseLabel("emr-6.5.0")
                .withSteps(stepConfig)
                .withApplications(spark)
                .withLogUri("s3://aws-logs-978841875846-us-east-1/elasticmapreduce/")
                .withServiceRole("EMR_DefaultRole")
                .withJobFlowRole("EMR_EC2_DefaultRole")
                .withInstances(new JobFlowInstancesConfig()
                        .withEc2SubnetId("subnet-0c5fd0bf46ee8b237")
                        .withInstanceCount(2)
                        .withKeepJobFlowAliveWhenNoSteps(false)
                        .withTerminationProtected(false)
                        .withMasterInstanceType("m5.xlarge")
                        .withSlaveInstanceType("m5.2xlarge")
                );
        emr.runJobFlow(request);
    }
```

Comment: [Does your cluster fulfill](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-managed-policy-fullaccess-v2.html) the `"aws:RequestTag/for-use-with-amazon-emr-managed-policies": "true"` condition the managed policy applies to `elasticmapreduce:RunJobFlow` actions?

Comment: thank you @fedonev, this fixed the issue but unfortunately I still have an error that I spent hours debugging and I cannot get to the bottom of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74276912/spinning-up-emr-from-aws-lambda-results-in-no-identity-based-policy-allows-the

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Fedonev pointed out, I was missing the user that `"aws:RequestTag/for-use-with-amazon-emr-managed-policies": "true"`

I fixed the issue by adding the tag on the `RunJobFlowRequest` creation:

```
.withTags(Collections.singleton(new Tag("for-use-with-amazon-emr-managed-policies", "true")))
```